# C3.js loosing values on x-axis labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

**QUESTION:**
I have created a line chart using C3.js that is updating its values every 2 seconds.
To achieve this goal i use the following code.

**UPDATE:**
I have noticed that this is happening when i'm swapping from a tab to another of the bowser.Let's say chart is on TAB1 and i swap to TAB2 for 5 minutes, when i get back to TAB1 i have lost some label as you can see in screenshots below and time on the X-axis is 5 minutes later too...

**UPDATE2**
The problem is related to setInterval almost for sure.

```
function drawChart1()
{
 var chart = c3.generate({
     bindto: '#chart11',
    //Size of the chart
    size: {
        height: 250,
        width: 952
    },
    data: { 
        x: 'x',
        columns: []
    },
    //Color of the lines
     color: {
        pattern: [ '#ff9896', '#9edae5']
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            //show: false,
            label: 'Time',
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%H:%M:%S',
                  //format: '%H:%M',
            }
        },
        y: {
            //http://c3js.org/samples/axes_label_position.html
            label: 'Kbps'
        },
    },
    legend: {
        //position: 'right'
    }
});
var chartObj = {
   "chart": chart,
   "redrawArgs": {},
   "truncThreshold": undefined
}


var date = Date.now();
var timeInc = 2000;
//Update values every x seconds 
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    var dataCols = [];
    date = date + timeInc;
    var minX = date - 10000;
    var maxX = date;
    var redrawArgs = chartObj.redrawArgs;
    if (!chartObj.truncThreshold) {
        chartObj.truncThreshold = maxX;
    } else if (minX > chartObj.truncThreshold) {
        redrawArgs.length = 1;
    } else {
        redrawArgs.length = 0;
    }
    chartObj.chart.axis.range({max: {x: maxX}, min: {x: minX}});
    redrawArgs.duration = 0;


    var TraficDown1 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    var TraficUp1 =   1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

    dataCols.push(['x', date]);
    dataCols.push(['Kbps UP', TraficUp1]);
    dataCols.push(['Kbps DOWN', TraficDown1])
    redrawArgs.columns = dataCols;

    chartObj.chart.flow(redrawArgs);
}, 2000);
}
```

For some time the code is working as intended:

[image]

Problem is that after some minutes I got this strange behaviour, where values are missing on x axis.

[image]

Someone can give me some hints? I'm using c3.js and D3.js v3.

Answer (score 0):

found it on here https://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-culling

```
axis: {
    x: {
        culling: false, // <-- THIS!
        //show: false,
        label: 'Time',
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
            format: '%H:%M:%S',
              //format: '%H:%M',
        }
    },
```